# nodejs - fs.readdir return list of files with replacing underscore with space

Tags: node.js, fs

Following script return list of files array but it changes file names with underscore to space. 
abc_xyz.json becomes abc xyz.json

any idea why?

```
async getFileList() {
    try {
      await util.promisify(fs.readdir)(this.tDir, (err, files) => {
        if (err === null) {
         console.log(files);
        } else {
          console.log(err.message);
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
console.log(error.message);
    }
  }
```

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback

Comment: Are you sure that it's not a matter of font that you use? Try to copy&paste result to another editor and check if underscore is present. Seriously.

Comment: @Developer I checked your code in my system. I don't see that behavior

Comment: @hsz Yes you seems right. I console this console.log(test_test2_test3, files); and I got this test test2 test3 [abc xyz.json] I am using bash terminal with Visual Source code on Cenots 7.6.. Now I need to work out what it is causing, that is relief that program is working ok. :)